# Install4j Constants Casuing Build Failures

Tags: java, install4j

Not sure if anyone else has ever come across this error but I'm updating an existing Install4j installation project. I noticed that whenever install4j's context is used the string is directly used. 
For example:

```
context.setVariable("somekey", "Some value");
```

I was thinking it would be awesome to move "somekey" into a java class where constants could be shared throughout install4j and the java code.

I created a class like so:

```
public class InstallerContextConstants {
    public static String KEY = "STRING_KEY";
}
```

So I go to add this to a screen's pre-activiation script like so:

```
import com.somepackage.InstallerContextConstants;
Util.showMessage(InstallerContextConstants.APPLICATION_ONLY_INSTALL);
```

However this will not compile...? It's giving me:

```
install4j: compilation failed. Reason: com.ejt.a.c.g: Failed to compile script
----------
In application "Installer", property "Help customizer script":
1. WARNING in /private/var/folders/n7/vjsf1vp56s13hzpgypthp2_h0000gp/T/script4119340027951579520.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_1.java (at line *19)
        private void eval(final com.install4j.api.context.InstallerContext context, final java.util.List options) throws Exception {
                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
----------
In application "Installer", property "Help customizer script":
2. WARNING in /private/var/folders/n7/vjsf1vp56s13hzpgypthp2_h0000gp/T/script4119340027951579520.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_1.java (at line 1)
        if (Util.isLinux()) options.add(new String[] { "--skip-precheck", "Bypasses Installer precheck checks. Note this must be the *first* argument."});
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type safety: The method add(Object) belongs to the raw type List. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
----------
In application "Installer", property "Help customizer script":
3. WARNING in /private/var/folders/n7/vjsf1vp56s13hzpgypthp2_h0000gp/T/script4119340027951579520.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_1.java (at line *24)
        eval((com.install4j.api.context.InstallerContext)parameters[0], (java.util.List)parameters[1]);
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
----------
----------
In screen "[Additional confirmations]", property "Pre-activation expression":
4. ERROR in /private/var/folders/n7/vjsf1vp56s13hzpgypthp2_h0000gp/T/script4119340027951579520.java.dir/com/install4j/script/I4jScript_Internal_35.java (at line 5)
        Util.showMessage(InstallerContextConstants.KEY);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KEY cannot be resolved or is not a field
----------
4 problems (1 error, 3 warnings)
```

Yet if i use any of the install4j string constants it works. http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/javadoc/constant-values.html

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, your approach should work, I would guess that the correct compiled class has not been added under Installer->Custom Code & Resources.

However, it's much easier to click on "Edit code" on the Installer->Custom Code & Resources step, this will bring up an editor for the static definitions that are available to all scripts.

If you add

```
static String KEY = "STRING_KEY";
```

there, then you can use `KEY` in any script without any import:

```
context.setVariable(KEY, "Some value");
```

Comment: I have some custom code as well that I would like to use the ```KEY``` variable. If I add it to the Resource step as a static definition, would I still be able to access it from the custom code?

Comment: Is that custom code in class files that are compiled outside of install4j? Then you would have to add the definitions in an external class file.